# gridview devexpress cuts off my decimal

Tags: gridview, devexpress

my grid view keeps cutting out all my decimal from my SQL query, when I format it, it just adds in a .00
on my db query, I have price values. which have decimal value of 2. example 99.99 but when its displays on my grid view, it cuts off my .99

I tried to add a repository item on the column edit, but its still doing that. now it gives me 99.00. this is wrong

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the format string for your column. For ASPxGridView and currency columns it looks something like this:

```
<dvx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="$Total" FieldName="GrandTotal" Width="90">
    <PropertiesTextEdit DisplayFormatString="C"></PropertiesTextEdit>
</dvx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

HTH